# Implementing behaviour from one menu item to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash

I am currently learning to program in JavaScript and I'm trying to modify an application for a personal project. The application has two main functions.

First the application creates a hash of a file uploaded by the user (which is then uploaded to the blockchain, but this side of things is fully functional), and if a hash of a particular file is already in the blockchain when trying to upload, the user gets an appropriate message letting him know this.

The second function, or menuItem, of the application allows the user to input a hash to see if its stored in the blockchain and if so, it displays when the original file has been uploaded and also returns the hash.

Here is the code of the app:

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
webServiceErrorStatus: null,
isUploadLoading: false,
isSearchLoading: false,
isReaderError: false,
isAfterUpload: false,
isAfterSearch: false,
fileHash: '',
fileInfo: null,
uploadedHashes: []
}

constructor() {
super();
this.WebService = null;
}

async componentWillMount() {
this.WebService = new WebService();
this.setState({
  fileInfo: new file()
});
}

fileHashChanged = event => {
this.setState({
  webServiceErrorStatus: null,
  isAfterSearch: false,
  fileHash: event.target.value,
});
};

searchFormSubmitted = async () => {
this.setState({
  isSearchLoading: true
});

var response = await this.WebService.getFileAsync(this.state.fileHash);

if(response instanceof WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum) {
  this.setState({
    webServiceErrorStatus: response
  });
}
else {
  this.setState({
    fileInfo: response,
    isAfterSearch: true
  });
}

this.setState({
  isSearchLoading: false
});
};

fileDropped = async (acceptedFiles) => {
acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
  this.setState({
    isUploadLoading: true,
    webServiceErrorStatus: null,
    isReaderError : false
  });

  var uploadedHashes = [];

  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onerror = () => {
    console.log('file reading has failed');
    this.setState({
      isUploadLoading: false,
      isReaderError: true
    });
  }

  reader.onload = async () => {
    const fileAsArrayBuffer = reader.result;
    var response = await this.WebService.addFileAsync(fileAsArrayBuffer);

    if(response instanceof WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum) {
      this.setState({
        webServiceErrorStatus: response,
        isUploadLoading: false
      });
    }
    else {
      uploadedHashes.push(response.fileHash)
      var tempUploadedHashes = this.state.uploadedHashes;
      tempUploadedHashes.push(...uploadedHashes);

      console.log(response);

      this.setState({
        isAfterUpload: true,
        uploadedHashes: tempUploadedHashes,
        isUploadLoading: false
      });
```

Along with the two menuItems:

```
{ menuItem: {content: 'Upload', icon:'upload', key: 'Upload'}, render: () =>
                <Tab.Pane className='tabPane'>
                  <Segment basic loading={this.state.isUploadLoading}>
                    <Form error={this.state.webServiceErrorStatus === WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum.DifferentAddError}>
                      <Header color='black' as='h2'>Upload</Header>
                      <ReactDropzone multiple={false}
                        className='dropZoneDefaultState'
                        acceptClassName='dropZoneAcceptState'
                        rejectClassName='dropZoneRejectState'
                        onDrop={this.fileDropped}>
                        <Segment basic>
                          <Icon disabled name='file outline' size='massive' color='black'/>
                          <Header as='h4' color='black'>Drop file or click to upload </Header>
                        </Segment>
                      </ReactDropzone>
                      <Message error header='Action Error' content='Something went wrong. Please contact with system administrator.' />
                    </Form>
                    {this.state.isAfterUpload && this.state.uploadedHashes.length > 0 &&
                      <Segment raised>
                        <Header color='black' as='h3'>Uploaded files hash list:</Header>
                        <List ordered relaxed style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>
                          {this.state.uploadedHashes.map((hash, index) =>
                            <List.Item key={index}>
                              <List.Header>
                                {hash}
                              </List.Header>
                            </List.Item>)}
                        </List>
                      </Segment>}
                    {this.state.webServiceErrorStatus === WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum.FileAlreadyExists &&
                      <Segment raised>
                        <Header color='black' as='h3'>File already exists!</Header>
                      </Segment>}
                    {this.state.isReaderError &&
                      <Segment raised>
                        <Header color='red' as='h3'>Problem with reading file!</Header>
                      </Segment>}
                  </Segment>
```

and

```
{ menuItem: {content: 'Search', icon:'search', key: 'Search'}, render: () =>
                <Tab.Pane className='tabPane'>
                  <Segment basic loading={this.state.isSearchLoading}>
                    <Header color='black' as='h2'>Search</Header>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.searchFormSubmitted} error={this.state.webServiceErrorStatus === WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum.DifferentGetError}>
                      <Form.Input fluid
                        action={{disabled: this.state.fileHash === '', icon: 'search'}}
                        placeholder='Provide file hash...'
                        type='text' value={this.state.fileHash}
                        onChange={this.fileHashChanged} />
                      <Message error header='Action Error' content='Something went wrong. Please contact with system administrator.' />
                    </Form>
                    {this.state.fileHash !== '' && this.state.isAfterSearch &&
                      <Segment raised>
                            <Header color='black' as='h3'>This file exists in blockchain:</Header>
                            <List relaxed>
                              <List.Item>
                                <List.Header>Upload Time</List.Header>
                                <List.Description>
                                  {this.state.fileInfo.time}
                                </List.Description>
                              </List.Item>
                              <List.Item>
                                <List.Header>Hash</List.Header>
                                <List.Description>
                                  {this.state.fileInfo.hash}
                                </List.Description>
                              </List.Item>
                              <List.Item>
                                <List.Content>
                                  <List.Description>
                                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={'http://' + this.state.fileInfo.url}>{this.state.fileInfo.url}</a>
                                  </List.Description>
                                </List.Content>
                              </List.Item>
                            </List>
                      </Segment>}
                      {this.state.webServiceErrorStatus === WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum.FileNotExist &&
                        <Segment>
                          <Header color='red' as='h3'>This VNFD does not match anything in blockchain.</Header>
                        </Segment>}
                  </Segment>
```

I would like to display the upload time and hash value from the second menuItem in the first menuItem when the user uploads a file that already has its hash in the blockchain, since I would like to remove the second function completely. I know this is it not as simple as moving {this.state.fileInfo.time} or {this.state.fileInfo.hash} over to the first menuItem, but I can't figure out how to go about making them work there.

Can anyone please explain to me why simply adding them to   {this.state.webServiceErrorStatus === WebServiceErrorStatusesEnum.FileAlreadyExists in the first menuItem won't work, and how I can fix it?

Comment: "When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem." https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example